# Number of pages - problem with first number

Tags: memoir, page-numbering, roman-numerals

I found out to have some issues with numbering pages. I use 'roman' style for index, and 'arabic' for the other pages but here is the problem: I would like to start with chapter on the right and page number 1.
I use 'memoir' as class and I'm not able to set this. Could anybody help me? Thanks a lot

```
 `%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------`-------------------
    %   PREAMBOLO
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openleft]{memoir}
    %\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openany]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   Pacchetti ed impostazioni generali

    \usepackage{plain}
    \usepackage{setspace}

    %--------------------------------------------------------------------
    %------------------------- N E N A  layout ----------------------
    % Better page layout for A4 paper, see memoir manual.
    \settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
    \setlength{\trimtop}{0pt} 
    \setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth} 
    \addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth} 
    \settypeblocksize{634pt}{448.13pt}{*} 
    \setulmargins{4cm}{*}{*} 
    \setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5} 
    \setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip} 
    \setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip} 
    \setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*} 
    \checkandfixthelayout
    %
    \frenchspacing
    % Font with math support: New Century Schoolbook
    \usepackage{fouriernc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %
    \OnehalfSpacing 
    %
    % Sets numbering division level
    \setsecnumdepth{subsection} 
    \maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
    %
    \usepackage{float}                      %Helps to place figures, tables, etc. 

    \usepackage{calc,soul,fourier}
    \makeatletter 
    \newlength\dlf@normtxtw 
    \setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth} 
    \newsavebox{\feline@chapter} 
    \newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
        \sbox\feline@chapter{% 
            \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
                \colorbox{white}{\color{black}\thechapter}% 
            }}%
            \rotatebox{0}{% 
                \resizebox{%
                    \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}% 
                {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
            \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
    } 
    \newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
        \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}% 
        \makebox[0pt][c]{% aka \rlap
            \makebox[0cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
        }}

    \makechapterstyle{daleifmodif}{
        \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape} 
        \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\scshape} 
        \renewcommand\chapternamenum{} \renewcommand\printchaptername{} 
        \renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[1.5cm]} 
        \renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip} 
        \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\color{gray}\chaptitlefont ##1\raggedleft}
    } 
    \makeatother 
    \chapterstyle{daleifmodif}
    % The pages should be numbered consecutively at the bottom centre of the
    % page.
    \makepagestyle{myvf} 
    \makeoddfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
    \makeevenfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
    \makeheadrule{myvf}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness} 
    \makeevenhead{myvf}{\small\textsc{\leftmark}}{}{} 
    \makeoddhead{myvf}{}{}{\small\textsc{\rightmark}}
    \pagestyle{myvf}
    %
    % Oscar's command (it works):
    % Fills blank pages until next odd-numbered page. Used to emulate single-sided
    % frontmatter. This will work for title, abstract and declaration. Though the
    % contents sections will each start on an odd-numbered page they will
    % spill over onto the even-numbered pages if extending beyond one page
    % (hopefully, this is ok).
    \newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\doublepage}}
    %
    %
    % Creates indexes for Table of Contents, List of Figures, List of Tables and Index
    \makeindex


    \usepackage{import}

    % Add other packages needed for chapters here. For example:
    \usepackage{lipsum}                 %Needed to create dummy text
    \usepackage{amsfonts}                   %Calls Amer. Math. Soc. (AMS) fonts
    \usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}            %Writes maths centred down
    \usepackage{stmaryrd}                   %New AMS symbols
    \usepackage{amssymb}                    %Calls AMS symbols
    \usepackage{amsthm}                 %Calls AMS theorem environment
    \usepackage{newlfont}                   %Helpful package for fonts and symbols
    \usepackage{layouts}                    %Layout diagrams
    \usepackage{graphicx}                   %Calls figure environment
    \usepackage{longtable,rotating}         %Long tab environments including rotation. 
                                        \usepackage{wasysym}                    %More math symbols
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}                   %Even more math symbols
    \usepackage{verbatim}                   %Permits pre-formated text insertion
    \usepackage{upgreek }                   %Calls other kind of greek alphabet
    \usepackage{latexsym}                   %Extra symbols
    \usepackage[square,numbers,
                 sort&compress]{natbib}     %Calls bibliography commands 
    \usepackage{url}                        %Supports url commands
    \usepackage{etex}                       %eTeXÕs extended support for counters
    \usepackage{fixltx2e}                   %Eliminates some in felicities of the 
                                        %original LaTeX kernel
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}     %For languages characters and hyphenation
    \usepackage{color}                                  %Creates coloured text and background
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,
                 allcolors=black]{hyperref}              %Creates hyperlinks in cross references
    \usepackage{memhfixc}                   %Must be used on memoir document 
                                        %class after hyperref
    \usepackage{enumerate}                  %For enumeration counter
    \usepackage{footnote}                   %For footnotes
    \usepackage{microtype}                  %Makes pdf look better.
    \usepackage{rotfloat}                   %For rotating and float environments as tables, 
                                        %figures, etc. 
    \usepackage{alltt}                      %LaTeX commands are not disabled in 
                                        %Reduce widows  (the last line of a paragraph at the start of a page) and orphans 
    % (the first line of paragraph at the end of a page)
    \widowpenalty=1000
    \clubpenalty=1000
    %


    %--------------------------------------------------------------------
    % supporto lettere accentate
    %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % per Linux (richiede il pacchetto unicode);
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    %
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{bibentry}


    %\singlespacing

    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %Formato titolo
    \usepackage{titlesec} % per formato custom dei titoli dei capitoli
    \titleformat{\chapter}
            {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}

          \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0in}{0.1in}
          \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0.20in}{0.1in}
          \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0.10in}{0.08in}
          \titlespacing*{\paragraph}{5mm}{0.02in}{5mm}
          \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0.02in}{0in}


    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{20pt}
    \titleformat*{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape}
    \titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries\scshape}
    \titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\scshape}

    \titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{200pt}{50pt}{20pt}
    \titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\large\bfseries\scshape\color{gray}}

    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openleft\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{\par}{}{}
    \makeatother



    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   DOCUMENTO
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



        \begin{document}
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   Frontespizio

     \pagenumbering{gobble} 
    % \input{pagina_iniziale}
     \clearpage

    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   Indice con numerazione romana delle pagine 



      \pagenumbering{roman}
      \cleardoublepage 
      \setcounter{page}{1}
        \tableofcontents
        \newpage
        \listoffigures

        \newpage
        \listoftables

        \newpage 
        \renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{\Large\bfseries\scshape\color{gray}Elenco dei listati} 
        \lstlistoflistings{}

    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % inizio numerazione pagine in numeri arabi
    %   \clearpage
      \cleardoublepage 
        \null
        \thispagestyle{plain} 
      \pagenumbering{arabic}
        \setcounter{page}{1}

    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   LISTA DEI CAPITOLI     
    %      \input{Agenda/Agenda}         
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   APPENDICI    

    %  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendice}
    %  \appendix
    %  \input{Appendice_A/Appendice_A}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: You shoule not use pagenumbering directly, use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, they reset automatically. I would not use `titlesec` with `memoir`, but if it works for you... You should also make this a minimal example, there are a lot of stuff here that are not relevant for your question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SE!
When you ask questions here, it's _really_ helpful (and would probably get you an answer faster) if you provide a _minimal_  example. i.e. it should include a `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` as you have done, but a minimal amount of code required to reproduce your problem. This way we can  go straight into solving the problem without spending time on understanding irrelevant things. See [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for more info on such examples.